# Cannot fire Bigcommerce webhooks

Tags: ruby, webhooks, bigcommerce

so far I've managed to create two webhooks by using their official gem (https://github.com/bigcommerce/bigcommerce-api-ruby) with the following events:

- store/order/statusUpdated
- store/app/uninstalled

The destination URL is a localhost tunnel managed by ngrok (the https) version.

```
status_update_hook = Bigcommerce::Webhook.create(connection: connection, headers: { is_active: true }, scope: 'store/order/statusUpdated', destination: 'https://myapp.ngrok.io/bigcommerce/notifications')
uninstall_hook = Bigcommerce::Webhook.create(connection: connection, headers: { is_active: true }, scope: 'store/app/uninstalled', destination:  'https://myapp.ngrok.io/bigcommerce/notifications')
```

The webhooks seems to be active and correctly created as I can retrieve and list them.

```
Bigcommerce::Webhook.all(connection:connection)
```

I manually created an order in my store dashboard but no matter to which state or how many states I change it, no notification is fired. Am I missing something?

Comment: Could you post your store hash? I can check the server logs to see if the webhook service is firing any hooks for your store.

Comment: Sure, @KarenWhite, it's 3nuz0ojp05

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception that I'm seeing in the logs is:

```
ExceptionMessage: true is not a valid header value
```

The "is-active" flag should be sent as part of the request body--your headers, if you choose to include them, would be an arbitrary key value pair that you can check at runtime to verify the hook's origin.

Here's an example request body:

```
{
  "scope": "store/order/*",
  "headers": {
    "X-Custom-Auth-Header": "{secret_auth_password}"
  },
  "destination": "https://app.example.com/orders",
  "is_active": true
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That was the problem indeed! Thanks!